Child routing not showing actual componet in React Routing
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './main.css'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Home } from './pages/index.jsx'


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/home',
    element: <Home></Home>,
    children:[
      {
        path: "team",
        element: <App></App>,
        //loader: teamLoader,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/form',
    element: <App></App>
  }
])
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

When I go for /Home it show Home component but when /Home/team it don't show App component it show Home component
I want to routing like module concept in Angular.

Do you have an outlet in the <Home /> component?

Thank you, @Konrad; actually, I am learning.

In React Router, when you define child routes, you need to ensure that the parent route can render the child routes. This typically involves using an <Outlet /> component from react-router-dom inside your parent component to specify where the child components should be rendered.
Here's a modified version of your code with these changes:
Main Routing Setup (main.jsx)
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './main.css'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Home } from './pages/index.jsx'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/home',
    element: <Home />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'team',
        element: <App />,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/form',
    element: <App />
  }
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

Home Component (Home.jsx)
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Component</h1>
      <Outlet /> {/* This is where child routes will be rendered */}
    </div>
  )
}

